# How to validate email user input in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

I'm setting up an automated browser using selenium. And I need the user input to complete the form, one of the fields I need is the email which needs to be valid.

I've already looked up and found nothing that matches

```
print(Fore.RED + (" "*7) + " | " + Fore.WHITE + "Email Adress: " + Style.RESET_ALL, end='')
email = input()


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

No results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to validate the email would be to use a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/). I found a pre-made one [here](https://emailregex.com/), but there are many others online you can use if you require international character support or other specifics.

You'll need to import the `re` library to use regexes in python. `re.match(regex, string)` will return a [Match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) (that evaluates to true) if the string satisfies the regular expression, or false otherwise.

Here's my implementation. Note that program execution continues even if the email is invalid. You might choose to use a while loop and prompt the user continuously until a valid email is entered, or raise an exception in the else clause to terminate the program.

```py
from colorama import Fore, Style
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import re

print(Fore.RED + (" "*7) + " | " + Fore.WHITE +
      "Email Adress: " + Style.RESET_ALL, end='')
email = input()

if re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", email): # if the email is valid
    print("That's a valid email!")
else:
    print("That's an invalid email!") # or raise exception to stop execution 

# do Selenium stuff
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Edit: Here's how I would loop until the email is valid...

```py
email_flag = False
while not email_flag:
    # prompt for email + get input
    print(Fore.RED + (" "*7) + " | " + Fore.WHITE +
      "Email Adress: " + Style.RESET_ALL, end='')
    email = input()

    # validate user input
    if re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", email):  # if the email is valid
        print("That's a valid email!")
        email_flag = True
    else:  # the email is invalid
        print("That's an invalid email!")
        # allow email_flag to remain false
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: No prob! Good luck with your browser project! :-)

Comment: One question: If the input is invailid how I can let the user to enter again until he enters something valid?

Comment: Edited the post. Enjoy!